# How do I find the latitude and longitude from Routeboxer for Google Maps API V3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, latitude-longitude

**Thanks in advance for any help you can provide!** I've reviewed several example sites, but I haven't been able to find a version of this code that matches what I'm trying to accomplish with my website (Ruby on Rails, 2.3.15, 1.8.7.)

**My Goal:**

In my website, I have a tool that lets users create a driving route. My goal is to give the user an option of clicking a "Show Nearby Points-of-Interest" checkbox before loading the map. If he does, I want the map to show POIs along the route.

**Where I Am**

I've implemented RouteBoxer, which I believe is my best option for finding Points of Interest along the route. Routeboxer is working for me; it draws boxes around any route I create. This is where I'm stuck, however. I've just got my route and a bunch of boxes on the screen. How can I actually get the latitude and longitude bounds from RouteBoxer? Then, how can I pass my data through RouteBoxer?

**Details**

I have a MySQL database named "myinfo" and a table in it named "masterlocations". Each location has an "ID", "Lat", "Long", "nickname", and other info.

In my map webpage controller, I played around and found that I could get a list of locations by hardcoding the latitude and longitude. The test looks like this:

```
@nearbylocations = Masterlocation.find(:all, :conditions => ["latitude > 25 AND latitude < 30"], :order => ['nickname asc'])
```

**Next Steps / Advice**

I think I need to figure out the latitude and longitude of the RouteBoxer polygon and then somehow see if any of my locations fall within this latitude and longitude. If they do, I then need to figure out a way so that the API creates markers for the POIs.

Do you have suggestions of how I can accomplish the above? I'm fairly new to both Ruby and Google Maps API V3, so sorry if I'm blowing past an obvious way of doing this. Any detail or code you can provide / link to would be fantastic! Thanks again for your time!

Answer (score 0):

You first get boxes from router box
    var boxes = routeBoxer.box(path, distance);

A box is just a series of lat/longs

```
for (var i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++) {

 var northeast = boxes[i].getNorthEast();
 var southwest = boxes[i].getSouthWest();
 var lat_north = northeast.lat();
 var long_east = northeast.lng();

 var lat_south = southwest.lat();
 var long_west = southwest.lng();
...
```

Now that you have the box bounds (the lat/longs that make it up), you can loop through all of your points to see if they reside within this box. To check this is just a simple 'does this point reside in this rectangle' algorithm (if point.x between box.left and box.right and point.y between box.top and box.bottom)

So summarily
Loop through boxes { Loop through coords { } }

Of course, this is just the start... This is a 'brute force' method where every point is checked against every box and depending on your route and number of boxes this can result in a huge number of permutations. There is ALOT of room for improvement using all kinds of algorithms. That was the fun part of this exercise when I did it - to use this or that; to do the crunching server side or client side...choices... Have fun...